# Managed (C#) control instantiated by unmanaged (C++) COM Server broken after Windows update

Tags: c#, c++, windows, com, registry

I have developed a managed (C#) control that will be consumed by an unmanaged (C++) COM Client.

Since I can't force users to elevate their permissions (even for installation), the control cannot be registered using an elevated (admin) account but must be registered by a regular non-elevated user account.  The unmanged application, likewise, must be run using a non-elevated user account.

So, I have designed the registration such that it adds registry keys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ (HKCU).  These registry keys are then seen by Windows as part of the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (HKCR) hive.

This worked fine for years, but within the last month, I have seen that Windows 7 Professional has begun to report E_CLASSNOTREGISTERED when instantiating this control.

When registered to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ (HKLM), the control can be instantiated even though the view from HKCR is identical in both cases.

From this I can only conclude that Windows is looking to HKLM to find registry information for my control even from a non-elevated COM Client (?!).

This is new behavior and only happens on Windows 7 machines that have the latest software patches from Microsoft.  Unpatched machines work as expected (i.e. I can instantiate my control when registered in HKCU).

This is a serious problem.

Is anyone aware of what change MS made to cause this and is there a way around it?

Thanks!

Comment: I've only ever used COM in two ways: either HKLM/HKCR registration, or through "side-by-side" assemblies (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SbsCs/about-side-by-side-assemblies-).  That second path may let you solve this issue.  Basically, you create a .NET style application manifest for your program that points to a local private (non-admin-required) COM object store, and the COM plumbing looks there before it looks in HKLM/HKCR before instantiating a COM Factory/COM Object.  It's been around since the Win2K or WinXP days, but it's not well known.

Comment: It took some doing, but this will work!  
  
I removed the traditional COM Registration and replaced it with [Registration-Free COM Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1h056h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  
  
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using ["side-by-side" assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SbsCs/about-side-by-side-assemblies-). Basically, you create a .NET style application manifest for your program that points to a local private (non-admin-required) COM object store, and the COM plumbing looks there before it looks in HKLM/HKCR before instantiating a COM Factory/COM Object. It's been around since the Win2K or WinXP days, but it's not well known.